# Ansible: Other option available for telnet check of open ports?

Tags: ansible, testing, ports

I'm new to Ansible. Here's my task ...

I have 400+ hosts, and I need to verify if 5 different ports are open from their end to our web server.

Individually, I could log in and run:

```
telnet mywebserver.com 443
telnet mywebserver.com 80
telnet mywebserver.com 8443
```

..and so on..

What module or plugin could be used in Ansible so I could automate this, and have it report the results (whether open or closed ports) back to my Ansible server?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use the Ansible [wait_for](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/wait_for_module.html) module which checks a specific TCP port is open.

Since in this case, all ports should be open already, we can use a minimal no. of retries, just enough to cover network issues:

```
- name: Check all port numbers are accessible from the current host
  wait_for:
    host: mywebserver.com
    port: "{{ item }}"
    state: started         # Port should be open
    delay: 0               # No wait before first check (sec)
    timeout: 3             # Stop checking after timeout (sec)
  ignore_errors: yes
  with_items:
    - 443
    - 80
    - 80443
```

By default, Ansible will check once every second (configurable in Ansible 2.3 using the `sleep` attribute), so this will check 3 times per port.

Run this in a playbook against your inventory of 400+ hosts - Ansible will check in parallel that all hosts can reach `mywebserver.com` on those ports.

- the parallelism is subject to the [forks setting](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_configuration.html#forks) in your `ansible.cfg`.

We use `ignore_errors: yes` here so that any errors are marked in red but do not stop execution.

Open ports are reported as `ok` items in output and closed ports are reported as `failed` (you must use `-vv` flag on `ansible-playbook` to see this output).

#### Fine-tuning output

If you want more specific output for the success and failure cases, the code must be more complex, adding a second task:

- `wait_for` task must `register` a variable
- the second task produces output using `debug` based on success/failure condition (e.g. using Jinja2 [conditional expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14215034/992887))
- then you need to put both these tasks in an include file (without any `with_items` loop), and write a main playbook task that uses an `include` ... `with_items` to call the include file once per port.

Comment: Importantly they'd need to set `host: mywebserver.com`.

Comment: @XiongChiamiov - `host: x` is not required.  I just re-tested with Ansible 2.3.1 and the `host` attribute of `wait_for` tasks defaults to the current server being processed from inventory.

Comment: Exactly, which is why OP needs to override it: they're testing connectivity *to another webserver* from all of their servers (re-read the question).

Comment: Good point, have updated the answer with `hosts` attribute.

Comment: Thank you! This works for me, and gives me enough to work on.

Comment: Have to mention that wait_for works only for TCP ports

Comment: @storm - good point, edited to mention TCP only for wait_for.  However, checking for open UDP ports is hard because it has no concept of a connection (only what the application defines) - a UDP check would require various steps beyond scope of Ansible - see [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/26542/20183).

Comment: Ansible 2.5 has deprecated `with_items` etc, replacing them with the `loop` construct - see [this section](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/porting_guides/porting_guide_2.5.html#with-items) of the Ansible 2.5 porting guide.  You might want to do a `set_fact` to create a `ports` fact containing list of ports, then use `ports` instead of the `items` in porting guide.

Comment: Actually Ansible 2.5 did not deprecate with_items and other lookup-based loops, though it did deprecate some other with* loops - see the top of docs page on loops.  However, it  is possible to re-write them with the `loop` construct.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no built-in module for this purpose, but you can use `shell` + `nc`:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - shell: nc -z -w 1 -G 1 my.hostname.com {{ item }} || echo "Port {{ item }} is closed"
      with_items: [80,443,8443]
```

Comment: Thank you, this works also, but I opted to go with first suggestion as it allows me to further customize the play.

Comment: What is `-G 1` I can't find it in the man pages?

Comment: @Ionix According to http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/nc.traditional.1.html, it's source-routing pointer

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wait_for](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/wait_for_module.html#synopsis) module for the same

example quoted from the documentation:

```
- name: Wait 300 seconds for port 8000 of any IP to close active connections, don't start checking for 10 seconds
  wait_for:
    host: 0.0.0.0
    port: 8000
    delay: 10
    state: drained
```

Comment: Please try to format your post properly, all site on StackExchange network allow the same markdown, documentation for formatting is [here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)

Comment: BTW I fail too see what this answer adds which is not in RichVel answer already

Answer (score 0):

We use our tool dda-serverspec (https://github.com/DomainDrivenArchitecture/dda-serverspec-crate) for such tasks. You may define your expectation

`{:netcat [{:host "mywebserver.com" :port "443"}
          {:host "telnet mywebserver.com" :port "80"}
          {:host "telnet mywebserver.com" :port "8443"}]}`

and test these expectation either against localhost or remote by ssh.
For remote tests you've to define a targets:

`{:existing [{:node-name "test-vm1"

             :node-ip "35.157.19.218"}

            {:node-name "test-vm2"
             :node-ip "18.194.113.138"}]
 :provisioning-user
  {:login "ubuntu"}}`

You may run the test by `java -jar dda-serverspec.jar --targets targets.edn serverspec.edn`